# When does a card switch to transmission mode, and can it be done forcefully?

Tags: smartcard

Quoting from EMV Book 1:

> This contact is used as an input (reception mode) to receive data from the terminal or as an output (transmission mode) to transmit data to the terminal. During operation, the ICC and the terminal shall not both be in transmission mode. In the event that this condition occurs, the state (voltage level) of the I/O contact is indeterminate and no damage shall occur to the ICC.

However, there is some ambiguity in the docs regarding **when** then card exactly switches to transmission mode in typical steps of the EMV transaction.

1. What is the exact procedure with which the card switches to transmission mode after receiving a command-APDU?
2. Can the card (theoretically) switch to transmission mode at any point it likes in the transaction?

Edit 1:
3. How does the transaction recover if the terminal and card are accidentally set in transmission mode?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever card responds to the command, I/O line of the card is set to transmission mode and I/O of the terminal is set to reception mode. The asynchronous half-duplex communication between the card and terminal is maintained by **Bit Duration** which calculates the time it takes to send character frame. This time is based on clock frequency of the terminal.

EMV Book 1, **7** - **Physical Transportation of Characters**

> During the transaction process, data is passed bi-directionally between the terminal and the ICC over the I/O line in an asynchronous half duplex manner. A clock signal is provided to the ICC by the terminal, and this shall be used to control the timing of this exchange.

> **7.1 Bit Duration**

> The bit duration used on the I/O line is defined as an elementary time unit (etu). A linear relationship exists between the etu on the I/O line and CLK frequency (*f*).

The default state for I/O line is reception mode. Only when command or response is sent, I/O line becomes transmissive of one of them at the time. The voltage control of I/O line is operated by firmware. There's no ICC command to switch mode on demand. EMV specification doesn't cover requirements for damage control when both of them set their I/O line to transmission mode. But if that happens and I/O line is undamaged, the error detection and correction can trigger retransmission of invalid data or deactivation of the ICC contacts. See **9.2.3 Error Detection and Correction** and its follow-up sections.

Answer (score 0):

ISO-7816 defines the smart card standards. EMV is based on these as are most smartcards.
An APDU always expects at least a status response. Depending on the APDU the card may return data with the response, and the status indicates if more data can be received.

There are 44 open source EMV projects at https://github.com/topics/emv.
and 173 at https://github.com/topics/smartcard. These include host applications and card applets.